# Theorem 7.2 in General Topology by S. Willard (characterization of continuity using $f(\overline E) \subset \overline{f(E)}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation

> Theorem 7.2
>
> If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $f:X \to Y$, then the following are all equivalent :-
>
> I) $f$ is continuous.
>
> II) for each $E \subset X$, $f(\bar E) \subset \overline{f(E)}$.

Proof:- (II) $\implies$ (I)

> Let $x\in X$ and let $V$ be an open neighbourhood of $f(x)$.
>
> Set $E = X-f^{-1}(V)$ and $U=X-\bar E$.
>
> It is easy to verify that, since $f(\bar E) \subset \overline{f(E)}$, we have $x \in U $.
>
> It is even clearer that $f(U)\subset V$
>
> Hence $f$ is continuous at $x$

I don't understand this part of the proof. I cannot understand how  $x\in U$

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x\notin U$ then $x\in\bar{E}$ and hence $f(x)\in f(\bar{E})\subseteq\overline{f(E)}\subseteq\overline{f(X)\cap(X\setminus V)}\subseteq\overline{X\setminus V}$ by definition of $E$. Therefore every neighborhood of $f(x)$ touches $X\setminus V$ and also $V$ (since $f(x)\in V$). This means that $f(x)$ is in the boundary of $V$. But since $V$ is open the boundary of $V$ is equal to $\bar{V}\setminus V$ and in particular disjoint from $V$ - a contradiction to $f(x)\in V$.

Comment: $\overline{f(E)}\subseteq\overline{f(X)\cap(X\setminus V)}$ .This is not true

Comment: $f(E) =f(X)-f(f^{-1} (V)) \supset Y-V $ , because $f(f^{-1} (V)) \subset V $

Comment: $E=X\cap f^{-1}(V)^c$ and thus $f(E)=f(X)\cap f(f^{-1}(V)^c)$. Using $f(f^{-1}(V)^c)\subseteq V^c$ which is clear we obtain $f(E)\subseteq f(X)\cap V^c=f(X)\cap(X\setminus V)$. $(-)^c$ always denotes the complement of a set. I am quite sure that this is true.

Comment: $f(f^{-1}(V)^c)\subseteq V^c$ ,this is wrong

Comment: If $A \subseteq B$ , then $B^c \subseteq A^c $

Comment: If $a\notin f^{-1}(V)$ then $f(a)\notin V$ and thus $f(f^{-1}(V)^c)\subseteq V^c$. I don't see what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in \bar{E}$, i.e., $x \notin U $. Then, since $f(\bar{E}) \subset \bar{f(E)}$, $f(x) \in \bar{f(E)}$. This would imply that $V \cap f(E) \ne \varnothing $ which contradicts the definition of $E$. Hence $x \in U $.

Comment: $f(E) =Y-ff^{-1} (V) \supset Y-V $, If$f(E)= Y-V $. This would imply that $V \cap f(E)=\varnothing$